# IOS can't navigate from a table view controller to another one

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view controller `TeamsViewController` and when the user tap on a row, I want to go to `TeamTableViewController`, which is another table view controller,

This is my code inside the TeamsViewController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Team Information"]){
        if ([segue.description isKindOfClass:[TeamTableViewController class]]){
            TeamTableViewController * teamTableViewController = (TeamTableViewController*) segue.destinationViewController;
            [teamTableViewController setTeam:[self.teams objectAtIndex:self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row]];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"That is why ");
        }
    }
}
```

Always the `That is why` is getting printed. Why please?
In the current situation, the `TeamTableViewController` is shown but with no data. I send the data through the `setTeam` message, which is not executed at all.

Please check the image.

[image]

The cell's identifier and segue's identifier are 100% correct.

Could you help me please?

I appreciate your time and efforts.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `segue.description` to `segue.destinationViewController`. The description is of class `NSString`.

Comment: OMG, I can't believe I did it again. half an hour checking but couldn't notice that. Many thanks. I will accept your answer when the system allows

Comment: Dear, could you check my new question please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061743/ios-user-experience-for-allowing-user-to-change-map-type I appreciate your time and efforts